# Unexpected error when starting up the Firestore emulator using the Firebase CLI

Tags: windows, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I am getting this error when trying to start the firestore emulator using Firebase-Tools on Windows 10 downloaded and installed as instructed at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli:

```
> firebase emulators:start --only firestore --debug
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.578Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.580Z] Command:       C:\Users\henri\DOWNLO~1\firebase-tools-instant-win.exe C:\Users\henri\.cache\firebase\tools\lib\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase emulators:start --only firestore --debug
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.580Z] CLI Version:   7.12.1
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.580Z] Platform:      win32
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.580Z] Node Version:  v12.13.1
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.581Z] Time:          Tue Feb 11 2020 13:09:51 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.581Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.581Z]
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.588Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2020-02-11T12:09:51.588Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
!  Could not find config (firebase.json) so using defaults.
i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore
!  No Firestore rules file specified in firebase.json, using default rules.
i  firestore: Serving ALL traffic (including WebChannel) on http://localhost:8080
!  firestore: Support for WebChannel on a separate port (8081) is DEPRECATED and will go away soon. Please use port above instead.
[2020-02-11T12:09:53.617Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId
[2020-02-11T12:09:53.617Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download
[2020-02-11T12:09:53.617Z] Starting emulator firestore with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Duser.language=en","-jar","C:\\Users\\henri\\.cache\\firebase\\emulators\\cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.10.2.jar","--host","localhost","--port",8080,"--webchannel_port",8081],"optionalArgs":["port","webchannel_port","host","rules","functions_emulator"],"joinArgs":false}
i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
[2020-02-11T12:09:53.634Z] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\system32\firestore-debug.log'

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

**Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\system32\firestore-debug.log**

Should this file even be written to system32...? The latest stable version of java, nodejs and npm are installed:

```
C:\Users\henri>java --version
java 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

C:\Users\henri>npm --version
6.13.4

C:\Users\henri>node
Welcome to Node.js v12.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

Comment: I suggest posting your issue to the Firebase CLI GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools